# Local storage vs Cordova-sqlite-storage

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage, android-sqlite

When should I consider to use SQLite storage instead of Local Storage? 
I'll have like 3200 city names in my app some user information and 100-200 companies with a lot of fields where one of them is an array contains 1-30 times 15 fields. 
[image: A company in JSON]

Can I and should I store this much information in local storage or should use SQLite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit of localstorage is 5MB. If you think you need more space, you better choose SQLite. 
Under 5BM, you can choose what you want. For localstorage I usually use [localstorageDB](https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB) without problems. Anyway, one issue is related to localstorage: I've read somewhere that if iOS got no memory, he can delete your localstorage data to retrieve space. For this reason, you better consider your data as "not eternal" into the device and maybe refresh them sometimes via ajax calls to your main server, if needed.

Comment: I don't know how much characters are making 5 MB. Somewhere I read this: 2Mb of storage actually mean 1M chars you can save. I also need to synchronize the companies with the server. I guess now I know the answer.

Comment: 5MB are a lot of chars. I consider 1 char = 1 byte. So I think you can store 5M chars

Comment: I personally got that problem(memory full) before with localStorage in iOS and that's why I am using SQLite Storage now.

Comment: @Kirankumar please let me know if I can test SQLite db in chrome browser or not.

Comment: @MagicDragon, If you are talking about SQLite plugin then you can not.

Comment: Yeah I was talking about it. Meanwhile I found the answer and made me kinda sad. Its logical anyway since the plugin is using cordova.